# Live Stream on the fly generated video in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming

I have a problem where i'm not able to stream a video over the Network due to it being generated live. Currently it's working using MJPEG but thats slow (especially if not in the local network) and has much overhead. I receive the frames of the video as images and currently convert them to JPEG and then build an MJPEG stream.

Would it be possible to generate another stream directly? So for example "bake" the images into another type that isn't this heavy?
If not, i currently think of the option to use FFMPEG to capture the MJPEG strteam and pipe it's output back into the App. Now, with this approach, what format would be best suited and how would i live stream it? (eg. build a controller that correctly serves the FFMPEG pipe output (which, if it helps, i'm getting at a 4096 bytes large buffer)).

Saving the Video to Disk and then just multipart streaming the file is not an option as it would not be live anymore.

Comment: Probably you'll want to investigate into RTP/RTSP Protocols as well as H.264, WebM and their streaming formats. But you may also already get a step further by downscaling the jpegs in your MJPEG.

Comment: Also, there seem to be various nugets that wrap ffmpeg to be integrated into dotnet apps, even.

Comment: I'm already using such a package for FFMPEG (Xabe.FFMPEG). Also i looked into RTSP, however i didn't find documentation on how to create such a stream with asp.net. And consuming one wouldn't work as my server app generates the frames.